# How to add comments to individual order items when creating order from admin?

Tags: magento

When you do create order from the admin backend, how do you allow adding comments to each of the order items?

I thought of adding a comments custom option to all the products, then modify `template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml` to remove the `Comments` option from `getOptions()` before passing it to `decorateArray()`.

Was wondering if there is a better way.